# page number in table of contents (of its own page) incorrect

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

The pagenumbers of the "chapter" table of contents isn't consistent: in the table of contents is another number than on the page itself. It would be awesome if somebody could help me.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt,openright]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Einstellung der Eingabekodierung
\usepackage[inner=25mm,outer=35mm,top=20mm,bottom=30mm,]{geometry}          
\usepackage{emptypage}      % Keine Seitenzahlen auf Leerzeiten
\usepackage{fancyhdr}       % Anpassung von Kopf- und Fußzeilen

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
% titlepage

\input{inhalt/1 abstract} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Kurzfassung}

% Inhaltsverzeichnis
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{xy}
\chapter{xyz}
% ...

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{8} % Fortsetzung der Seitenzahl 

%\appendix

\end{document}
```

Comment: if your table of contents is more than one page you are adding `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}` too late as it is after the table of contents

Comment: do you really want to add the table of contents to the table of contents? Do you think people look in the table of contents to find the table of contents?

Comment: Yes, because my university wants that, I know its stupid. How can I solve this?

Comment: move the \addcontentsline up so that it is executed on the right page, e.g. `\clearpage\addcontentsline ... \tableofcontents`